# How to access particular fields from JSON content by using php?

Tags: php, json

i want to get the values of different fields in Json by using php

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php

Comment: Like your other question, you'll get more help if you post some code that you're having trouble with or asking a more specific question.

Comment: exact duplicate of your 5 minute old question [How to receive and use a json in ajax sended from php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317587/how-to-receive-and-use-a-json-in-ajax-sended-from-php). Are you for real?

Comment: Check out ["Writing the perfect question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for help on writing questions here on SO. Language barriers may make it difficult to ask a question well, but it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

json_decode($string) will return an object from which you can get the values you assigned.

For example:

```
$myObject = new MyObject();
$myObject -> att1 = 5;

$string = json_encode($myObject);

//here's how you get the value:

$myJsonDecodedObject = json_decode($string);
$value = $myJsonDecodedObject -> att1;
```

Comment: i tried this but doesn't work because i have a json which is a response from JSON/Atom Custom Search API.

Comment: Narrowing down your questiong or posting some code would help us give you an answer... have you tried that?

Comment: The JSON you're receiving is likely not well-formed. Or the data is too "deep" ["NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit."](http://php.net/json_decode) use `json_last_error()` as shown in the documentation to discover what went wrong during the decode.