# How to receive and use a json in ajax sended from php?

Tags: php, json

I want to receive json from php to ajax and want to access the different field values in json.

Comment: my god what are you talking about?

Comment: Please narrow down your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery it will be implementing something like this:

```
var user = {};

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://mysite.com/api/user.json',
  data: {'id': '42'},
  success: function(data){user = data;},
});

$('#name').val(user.name);
$('#email').val(user.email);
```

Answer (score 6):

On the PHP side, use `json_encode()` to convert your data to JSON, and write it out, then exit. Best send a content type header first, to make sure the receiving end recognizes it as JSON:

```
<?php
$response_data = whatever_function();
$response = json_encode($response_data);
header("Content-type: text/json");
echo $response;
exit;
```

On the client, your best bet is to use an existing AJAX framework, such as the AJAX functionality built into jQuery. Suppose your script is at `http://example.com/ajax.php`, and the client page is at `http://example.com/ajaxclient.html`, a suitable piece of jQuery would go something like:

```
$.getJSON('ajax.php', { /* GET data goes here */ }, function(data) {
    /* data contains the values you sent in your PHP script */
});
```