# Extract a specific item from json data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have an ajax call which returns the category list. I wish to extract each name from the list.
my ajax looks like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Client/GetCategoryList",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function () { alert("Error"); }
            });
        });
```

if i am using "dataType: "json"," then in the alert i found the result like

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

and if i comment the "dataType: "json" then the result is like

```
[{"iID":56,"strName":"as","strDescription":"as","strImage":""},{"iID":24,"strName":"laptop","strDescription":"laptops","strImage":"uploads/2dell.jpg"}, {"iID":14,"strName":"mobile","strDescription":"handsets","strImage":"uploads/14sams.jpeg"},{"iID":46,"strName":"sds","strDescription":"dsd","strImage":"uploads/Category/46bg.jpg"}]
```

I just wanted to extract the category name or strName from the data as a hyperlink . Any help will be highly appreciable.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your script is returning an array of 5 objects. You need to iterate over them and get the `strName` property of each.

Comment: Try this you can get your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317112/how-to-access-particular-fields-from-json-content-by-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var names = $.map(data, function(v){
    return v.strName;
});
```

Comment: @rns Np! I thought you could figure out the hyperlink part with this ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're returning an array, you need to loop over it:

```
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, el) {
            console.log(el.strName);
        });
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

You can extract "strName" by using `data.strName`  in success function of your ajax call;

Sorry i didn't see it is an array. you can try getJson method like:

```
$.getJSON(url, param ,function(data) { //url - return json page
   $.each(data, function() {
       alert(this.strName);
   });
};
```